# How to translate points on image after cropping it and resizing it?

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

I am creating a program which allows a user to annotate images with points.
This program allows user to zoom in an image so user can annotate more precisely.

Program zooms in an image doing the following:

1. Find the center of image
2. Find minimum and maximum coordinates of new cropped image relative to center
3. Crop image
4. Resize the image to original size

For this I have written the following Python code:

```py
import cv2
def zoom_image(original_image, cut_off_percentage, list_of_points):
    height, width = original_image.shape[:2]
    center_x, center_y = int(width/2), int(height/2)
    half_new_width = center_x - int(center_x * cut_off_percentage)
    half_new_height = center_y - int(center_y * cut_off_percentage)
    min_x, max_x = center_x - half_new_width, center_x + half_new_width
    min_y, max_y = center_y - half_new_height, center_y + half_new_height

     #I want to include max coordinates in new image, hence +1
    cropped = original_image[min_y:max_y+1, min_x:max_x+1]
    new_height, new_width = cropped.shape[:2]

    resized = cv2.resize(cropped, (width, height))
    translate_points(list_of_points, height, width, new_height, new_width, min_x, min_y)
```

I want to *resize* the image to original width and height so user always works on same "surface"
regardless of how zoomed image is.

The problem I encounter is how to correctly scale points (annotations) when doing this. My algorithm to do so was following:

1. Translate points on original image by subtracting `min_x` from x coordinate and `min_y` from y coordinate
2. Calculate constants for scaling x and y coordinates of points
3. Multiply coordinates by constants

For this I use the following Python code:

```py
import cv2
def translate_points(list_of_points, height, width, new_height, new_width, min_x, min_y):
    #Calculate constants for scaling points
    scale_x, scale_y = width / new_width, height / new_height

    #Translate and scale points
    for point in list_of_points:
        point.x = (point.x - min_x) * scale_x
        point.y = (point.y - min_y) * scale_y
```

This code **doesn't** work. If I zoom in once, it is hard to detect the offset of pixels but it happens. If I keep zooming in, it will be much easier to detect the "drift" of points. Here are images to provide examples. On original image (1440x850) I places a point in the middle of blue crosshair. The more I zoom in the image it is easier to see that algorithm doesn't work with bigger cut-ofs.

[Original image. Blue crosshair is middle point of an image. Red angles indicate what will be borders after image is zoomed once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrWDE.png)

[Image after zooming in once.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BomzW.png)

[Image after zooming in 5 times. Clearly, green point is no longer in the middle of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xC0B.png)

The `cut_off_percentage` I used is 15% (meaning that I keep 85% of width and height of original image, calculated from the center).

I have also tried the following library: [Augmentit python library](https://github.com/sandesha-hegde/augmentit)
Library has functions for cropping images and resizing them together with points. Library also causes the points to drift. This is expected since the code I implemented and library's functions use the same algorithm.

Additionally, I have checked whether this is a rounding problem. It is <strike>*not*.</strike> Library rounds the points after multiplying coordinates with scales. Regardless on how they are rounded, points are still off by 4-5 px. This increases the more I zoom in the picture.

**EDIT**: A more detailed explanation is given here since I didn't understand a given answer.

The following is an image of right human hand.

[Image of a hand in my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxTix.png)

Original dimension of this image is 1440 pixels in width and 850 pixels in height. As you can see in this image, I have annotated right wrist at location (756.0, 685.0). To check whether my program works correctly, I have opened this exact image in GIMP and placed a white point at location (756.0, 685.0). The result is following:

[Image of a hand in GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CNMO.png)

Coordinates in program work correctly. Now, if I were to calculate parameters given in first answer according to code given in first answer I get following:

`vec = [756, 685]`
`hh = 425`
`hw = 720`
`cov = [720, 425]`

These parameters make sense to me. Now I want to zoom the image to scale of 1.15. I crop the image by choosing center point and calculating `low` and `high` values which indicate what rectangle of image to keep and what to cut. On the following image you can see what is kept after cutting (everything inside red rectangle).

[What is kept when cutting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L85bE.png)

Lows and highs when cutting are:
`xb = [95,1349]`
`yb = [56,794]`

Size of cropped image: 1254 x 738

This cropped image will be resized back to original image. However, when I do that my annotation gets completely wrong coordinates when using parameters described above.

[After zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqxTe.png)

This is the code I used to crop, resize and rescale points, based on the first answer:

```py
width, height = image.shape[:2]
center_x, center_y = int(width / 2), int(height / 2)
scale = 1.15
scaled_width = int(center_x / scale)
scaled_height = int(center_y / scale)
xlow = center_x - scaled_width
xhigh = center_x + scaled_width
ylow = center_y - scaled_height
yhigh = center_y + scaled_height
xb = [xlow, xhigh]
yb = [ylow, yhigh]
cropped = image[yb[0]:yb[1], xb[0]:xb[1]]
resized = cv2.resize(cropped, (width, height), cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

#Rescaling poitns
cov = (width / 2, height / 2)
width, height = resized.shape[:2]
hw = width / 2
hh = height / 2
for point in points:
    x, y = point.scx, point.scy
    x -= xlow
    y -= ylow
    x -= cov[0] - (hw / scale)
    y -= cov[1] - (hh / scale)
    x *= scale
    y *= scale
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    point.set_coordinates(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked through my code and realized where I was making a mistake which caused points to be offset.

In my program, I have a canvas of specific size. The size of canvas is a constant and is always larger than images being drawn on canvas. When program draws an image on canvas it first resizes that image so it could fit on canvas. The size of resized image is somewhat smaller than size of canvas. Image is usually drawn starting from top left corner of canvas. Since I wanted to always draw image in the center of canvas, I shifted the location from top left corner of canvas to another point. This is what I didn't account when doing image zooming.

```py
def zoom(image, ratio, points, canvas_off_x, canvas_off_y):
    width, height = image.shape[:2]
    new_width, new_height = int(ratio * width), int(ratio * height)
    center_x, center_y = int(new_width / 2), int(new_height / 2)
    radius_x, radius_y = int(width / 2), int(height / 2)
    min_x, max_x = center_x - radius_x, center_x + radius_x
    min_y, max_y = center_y - radius_y, center_y + radius_y
    img_resized = cv2.resize(image, (new_width,new_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)   
    img_cropped = img_resized[min_y:max_y+1, min_x:max_x+1]
    for point in points:
        x, y = point.get_original_coordinates()
        x -= canvas_off_x
        y -= canvas_off_y
        x = int((x * ratio) - min_x + canvas_off_x)
        y = int((y * ratio) - min_y + canvas_off_y)
        point.set_scaled_coordinates(x, y)
```

In the code below `canvas_off_x` and `canvas_off_y` is the location of offset from top left corner of canvas

Answer (score 0):

So this really is an integer rounding issue. It's magnified at high zoom levels because being off by 1 pixel at 20x zoom throws you off much further. I tried out two versions of my crop-n-zoom gui. One with int rounding, another without.

You can see that the one with int rounding keeps approaching the correct position as the zoom grows, but as soon as the zoom takes another step, it rebounds back to being wrong. The non-rounded version sticks right up against the mid-lines (denoting the proper position) the whole time.

Note that the resized rectangle (the one drawn on the non-zoomed image) blurs past the midlines. This is because of the resize interpolation from OpenCV. The yellow rectangle that I'm using to check that my points are correctly scaling is redrawn on the zoomed frame so it stays crisp.

With Int Rounding

[image]

Without Int Rounding

[image]

I have the center-of-view locked to the bottom right corner of the rectangle for this demo.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# clamp value
def clamp(val, low, high):
    if val < low:
        return low;
    if val > high:
        return high;
    return val;

# bound the center-of-view
def boundCenter(cov, scale, hh, hw):
    # scale half res
    scaled_hw = int(hw / scale);
    scaled_hh = int(hh / scale);

    # bound
    xlow = scaled_hw;
    xhigh = (2*hw) - scaled_hw;
    ylow = scaled_hh;
    yhigh = (2*hh) - scaled_hh;
    cov[0] = clamp(cov[0], xlow, xhigh);
    cov[1] = clamp(cov[1], ylow, yhigh);

# do a zoomed view
def zoomView(orig, cov, scale, hh, hw):
    # calculate crop
    scaled_hh = int(hh / scale);
    scaled_hw = int(hw / scale);
    xlow = cov[0] - scaled_hw;
    xhigh = cov[0] + scaled_hw;
    ylow = cov[1] - scaled_hh;
    yhigh = cov[1] + scaled_hh;
    xb = [xlow, xhigh];
    yb = [ylow, yhigh];

    # crop and resize
    copy = np.copy(orig);
    crop = copy[yb[0]:yb[1], xb[0]:xb[1]];
    display = cv2.resize(crop, (width, height), cv2.INTER_CUBIC);
    return display;

# draw vector shape
def drawVec(img, vec, pos, cov, hh, hw, scale):
    con = [];
    for point in vec:
        # unpack point
        x,y = point;
        x += pos[0];
        y += pos[1];

        # here's the int version
        # Note: this is the same as xlow and ylow from the above function
        # x -= cov[0] - int(hw / scale);
        # y -= cov[1] - int(hh / scale);

        # rescale point
        x -= cov[0] - (hw / scale);
        y -= cov[1] - (hh / scale);
        x *= scale;
        y *= scale;
        x = int(x);
        y = int(y);

        # add
        con.append([x,y]);
    con = np.array(con);
    cv2.drawContours(img, [con], -1, (0,200,200), -1);

# font stuff
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
fontScale = 1;
fontColor = (255, 100, 0);
thickness = 2;

# draw blank
res = (800,1200,3);
blank = np.zeros(res, np.uint8);
print(blank.shape);

# draw a rectangle on the original
cv2.rectangle(blank, (100,100), (400,200), (200,150,0), -1);

# vectored shape
# comparison shape
bshape = [[100,100], [400,100], [400,200], [100,200]];
bpos = [0,0]; # offset
# random shape
vshape = [[148, 89], [245, 179], [299, 67], [326, 171], [385, 222], [291, 235], [291, 340], [229, 267], [89, 358], [151, 251], [57, 167], [167, 164]];
vpos = [100,100]; # offset

# get original image res
height, width = blank.shape[:2];
hh = int(height / 2);
hw = int(width / 2);

# center of view
cov = [600, 400];
camera_spd = 5;

# scale
scale = 1;
scale_step = 0.2;

# loop
done = False;
while not done:
    # crop and show image
    display = zoomView(blank, cov, scale, hh, hw);
    # drawVec(display, vshape, vpos, cov, hh, hw, scale);
    drawVec(display, bshape, bpos, cov, hh, hw, scale);

    # draw a dot in the middle
    cv2.circle(display, (hw, hh), 4, (0,0,255), -1);

    # draw center lines
    cv2.line(display, (hw,0), (hw,height), (0,0,255), 1);
    cv2.line(display, (0,hh), (width,hh), (0,0,255), 1);

    # draw zoom text
    cv2.putText(display, "Zoom: " + str(scale), (15,40), font,
                fontScale, fontColor, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA);

    # show
    cv2.imshow("Display", display);
    key = cv2.waitKey(1);

    # check keys
    done = key == ord('q');

    # Note: if you're actually gonna make a GUI
    # use the keyboard module or something else for this

    # wasd to move center-of-view
    if key == ord('d'):
        cov[0] += camera_spd;
    if key == ord('a'):
        cov[0] -= camera_spd;
    if key == ord('w'):
        cov[1] -= camera_spd;
    if key == ord('s'):
        cov[1] += camera_spd;

    # z,x to decrease/increase zoom (lower bound is 1.0)
    if key == ord('x'):
        scale += scale_step;
    if key == ord('z'):
        scale -= scale_step;
    scale = round(scale, 2);

    # bound cov
    boundCenter(cov, scale, hh, hw);
```

Edit: Explanation of the drawVec parameters

- img: The OpenCV image to be drawn on
- vec: A list of [x,y] points
- pos: The offset to draw those points at
- cov: Center-Of-View, where the middle of our zoomed display is pointed at
- hh:  Half-Height, the height of "img" divided by 2
- hw:  Half-Width, the width of "img" divided by 2

Comment: I wanted to try your code inside my program. Can you elaborate on parameters of ` drawVec` are? Why is `pos` always `[0,0]` in your code. You change values of `cov` for 5 depending on direction. How should I change it when zooming image? Do `hh` and `hw` stay the same regardless of times zoomed?